# json_decode() returns NULL because of double quotes

Tags: php, json

I have JSON string that I'm trying to parse using `json_decode($s,true)`.
If I `var_dump` my string, it looks like:

```
string(186) "[{"ta_id":97497,"partner_id":"229547","partner_url":"http://partner.com/deeplink/to/229547"},"ta_id":97832,"partner_id":"id34234","partner_url":"http://partner.com/deeplink/to/id34234"}]"
```

You can see those double quotes (and the wrong syntax highlighting) at the start of the line and that I suppose to be my problem. `json_last_error()` returns `4` (`JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX`)

How can I fix this? The string is fetched from `POST` data. Thanks

Comment: The double quotes aren't the issue here (that's just how PHP displays strings when you use `var_dump`).  You're missing a `{` before the 2nd `ta_id`.

Comment: OMG I'm so dump. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Your Json is not valid.

```
Parse error on line 7:
..."    },    "ta_id": 97832,    "partne
---------------------^
Expecting '}', ',', ']'
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you'll find that those double quotes are just the way `var_dump` is representing the string and not part of the problem.

Strip them away from the ends and [validate the JSON](http://jsonlint.com/) and you'll get:

```
[
    {
        "ta_id": 97497,
        "partner_id": "229547",
        "partner_url": "http://partner.com/deeplink/to/229547"
    },
    "ta_id": 97832,
    "partner_id": "id34234",
    "partner_url": "http://partner.com/deeplink/to/id34234"
}
]

Parse error on line 7:
..."    },    "ta_id": 97832,    "partne
---------------------^
Expecting '}', ',', ']'
```

You have an missing `{`.

Comment: Or rather, he's missing a `{`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat — Good spot.

Answer (score 1):

```
  [
    {
      "ta_id":97497,
      "partner_id":"229547",
      "partner_url":"http://partner.com/deeplink/to/229547"
    },
    "ta_id":97832,
    "partner_id":"id34234",
    "partner_url":"http://partner.com/deeplink/to/id34234"
  }
]
```

As you can see from this breakdown, you are missing a `{`. This is the cause of your syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

The double-quotes aren't the issue. You're missing an opening curly brace `{` in your JSON. The correct JSON string should be as follows:

```
[
    {
        "ta_id": 97497,
        "partner_id": 229547,
        "partner_url": "http://partner.com/deeplink/to/229547"
    },
    { <----------------------------- this was the problem
        "ta_id": 97832,
        "partner_id": "id34234",
        "partner_url": "http://partner.com/deeplink/to/id34234"
    }
]
```

Validating the JSON string using an online validation service such as [JSONLint.com](http://jsonlint.com) would have helped you find out the issue easily.